# I want to use 1 Combobox to navigate many sheets that refer to items that Combobox contain

Tags: excel, vba

I got 1 ComboBox1 contains 5 items. There is 1,2,3,4, and 5 and they all represent for Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3, Sheet4 and Sheet 5 respectively. If I chose item 1 in ComboBox, then I click on CommandButton1 then it will show up the Sheet1. The same if I chose item 2, 3, 4 or 5 it will show up Sheet2, Sheet3, Sheet4 and Sheet 5 respectively.

The problem is I want to use only 1 CommandButton to navigate those Sheets

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim a As Integer
    a = 3
If Not IsNumeric(TextBox2.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Only numbers allowed", vbCritical
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    TextBox2.SetFocus

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please Select the Stencil ID", vbCritical
    ComboBox1.Text = ""
    ComboBox1.SetFocus

ElseIf ComboBox1.Enabled = True Then
    a = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet10.Range("a3:a1000000"))
    a = a + 3
    Sheet10.Cells(a, 1) = TextBox2.Text
    Sheet10.Cells(a, 2) = ComboBox1.Text
    Sheet10.Cells(a, 3) = DTPicker1.Value
    Sheet10.Cells(a, 4) = TextBox1.Text

ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "1" Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Visible = True
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").Select

ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "2" Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = True
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("a1").Select

ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "3" Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Visible = True
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("a1").Select

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: the if condition checking on whether combo box is enabled is the first thing hit, so other code which checks for what option has been selected never gets called.  Refactor your code so it isn't a bit if else list

Answer (score 0):

Try arranging the code like this:

```
If Not IsNumeric(TextBox2.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Only numbers allowed", vbCritical
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    TextBox2.SetFocus

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please Select the Stencil ID", vbCritical
    ComboBox1.Text = ""
    ComboBox1.SetFocus
end if

If ComboBox1.Enabled = True Then
    a = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet10.Range("a3:a1000000"))
    a = a + 3
    Sheet10.Cells(a, 1) = TextBox2.Text
    Sheet10.Cells(a, 2) = ComboBox1.Text
    Sheet10.Cells(a, 3) = DTPicker1.Value
    Sheet10.Cells(a, 4) = TextBox1.Text
end if

If ComboBox1.Text = "1" Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Visible = True
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").Select

ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "2" Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = True
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("a1").Select

ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "3" Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Visible = True
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("a1").Select

End If
```